# $ works fine but $.ajax is not a function (not slim)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some problems with my jQuery code. I load jQuery (**not slim**) and $.ajax fail. '$' and 'jQuery' works fine.

Maybe it is a super simple solution, but i can't find one...

This is the first use of jQuery in my project.

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlBoard").on("change", function () {
            $list = $("#ddlRow");
            $.ajax({
                url: "Settings/row",
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: $("#ddlBoard").val() }, //id of the state which is used to extract cities
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    $list.empty();
                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                        $list.append('<option value="' + item["CityId"] + '"> ' + item["Name"] + ' </option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("err")
                    alert("Something went wrong call the police");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

... the whole thing is asp.net core MVC here is more ...

```
<form asp-controller="Settings" asp-action="Login" method="post">
<select id="ddlBoard" name="board">
            @if (userIndex == 0 || userData[userIndex].ProjectId == null)
            {
                <option selected disabled value="-1">Plantafel auswählen</option>
            }
            @for (int i = 0; i < projectData.Count; i++)
            {
                if (userIndex != 0 && userData[userIndex].ProjectId == projectData[i].Idx)
                {
                    <option selected value="@projectData[i].Idx">@projectData[i].projectName</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@projectData[i].Idx">@projectData[i].projectName</option>
                }
            }
        </select>



<!--Row-->
        <!--todo update this after project change and show only rows from one project-->
        <select id="ddlRow" name="row">
            @if (userIndex == 0 || userData[userIndex].RowId == null)
            {
                <option selected disabled value="-1">Zeile auswählen</option>
            }
            @for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Count; i++)
            {
                if (userIndex != 0 && userData[userIndex].RowId == rowData[i].Idx)
                {
                    <option selected value="@rowData[i].Idx">@rowData[i].RowName</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@rowData[i].Idx">@rowData[i].RowName</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
</form>
```

[image: Code as Screenshot]

Comment: Odds are that you are overwriting the jQuery loaded here with jQuery slim later on, but you haven't provided a [mcve] (there's no HTML to bind the event handler to) so it is untestable.

Comment: Another possibility is that somewhere you're doing $.ajax = ({})

Comment: This is my first use of jQuery in my project (no -> $.ajax = ({})). Without the import i can't call '$' (no override with slim)

Comment: Do `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);`. If the output looks something like this: `3.1.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/animatedSelector,-effects/Tween,-deprecated` You're using jQuery slim, either accidentally or intentionally

Comment: Output is: "3.4.1"

Comment: Was that placed just before the `$.ajax()` call?

Comment: Remember to clear your browser cache. hmmm MVC... I would say that validation plugin is overriding, but the jquery version looks fine.

Comment: new Screenshot shows that the jQuery import is directly in front of my script

Comment: Is that the only jQuery import on the page, at all?

Comment: Put the console.log inside the on change. Did you see the same version ?

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET Core MVC _Layout.cshtml file loads the slim version of jquery at the end of the file after @RenderBody() but before @RenderSection.

```
<!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> Slim version (=without AJAX)

Facepalm

Replace the slim import with a "normal" import

Thanks to filipe, it is possible to test for the correct version. Just do `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);` at the position where you have a problem

Comment: Yep, Microsoft fiddling with 3rd party libraries they don't understand (like when they broke Bootstrap with one line in site.css)